# How do I use 2 Layouts for Pages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout

All the pages on my site use the application layout. I want my static pages to also use the Static Pages layout. How do I use both layouts together?

Application Layout:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Static Pages Layout:

```
<div class="static">
</div>
```

Static page:

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

I want the page to result in:

```
 <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>

    <div class="static">
    <p>Hello</p>
    </div>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts

Inside your second layout, static pages layout:

## Static layout

```
<%= render :template => 'layouts/application' %>
```

## Application layout

```
<%= yield %>
```

## Controller where you want to use static layout

```
class AController
  layout 'static_layout'
```

`static_layout` should be in views/layouts.

I suppose you could use layout convention too:

```
class StaticController
```

And a file `app/views/layouts/static.html.erb`

Or select layout in `render` call:

```
render 'something', layout: 'static'
```

Comment: I tried static layout with and without "yield" and with and without specifying `yield static`, but i couldn't get it to nest properly within  application layout.

Comment: I suppose you should use `yield` in application as usual, and use static layout, let me update

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the used of the [`yield`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield)

application.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <% if @static %>
      <div class="static">
        <%= yield :static %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

static_page.html.erb

```
<% content_for :static do %>
  <p>Hello</p>
<% end %>
```

Only thin you need to take care now in static page controller action set a `@static` to true

Answer (score 0):

Hi In controller use `layout`

```
class StaticPagesController < .....

 # you can apply only,execpt if you want 
 layout 'static'

  def home

  end
end
```